# Transferring .txt data into .sdf Using Visual C# to display

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm using Visual c# express 2008.

I have a huge text file that has data similar to this: "text/text/text/text"

I'm using a delimiter to separate the data.

Now I want to transfer this data to an .sdf file that will be displayed in table format through the windowsformapplication using dataGridView.

I already created an sdf with a table (and columns).

I know how to access the .sdf and display through the dataGridView.

My problem is I have no idea how to transfer the data from the txt to the sdf.

I don't want to do it manually because the txt file contains around 20,000 worth of lines.

Resources: I've recycled code from 
http://dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Thanks to anyone who can help. :3 Ree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory (not tested) SqlBulkCopy works with SDF, so then all you need is an IDataReader. If you search for "fast CsvReader" you should find one on codeproject; this works with any delimiter and should work perfectly with SqlBulkCopy (I've used it this way multiple times, although not with sdf).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: Thanks I won't really use or alter the csv but the code gave me an idea how to approach mine. :D

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could try my new  Csv2sqlce utility: http://csv2sqlce.codeplex.com